# Testing a specific implementation with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Update 1, more details

My question was hard to interpret, sorry for that....

Simple question...
How do you test a specific implementation with Moq?

```
interface IShipping
{
    int CalculateCost();
}

class TruckShipping: IShipping
{
    int CalculateCost()
    {
        return 9;
    }
}

class Shipping: IShipping
{
    int CalculateCost()
    {
        return 5;
    }
}

class CalculateSomethingMore
{
    IShipping _shipping;
    CalculateSomethingMore(IShipping shipping)
    {
        // Here I want the TruckShipping implementation!
        _shipping = shipping;
    }
    DoCalc()
    {
        return _shipping.CalculateCost * 2;
    }
 }
```

Without mock it would probably look like (if you don't use DI)
TEST:

```
var truckShipping = new TruckShipping();
var advancedCalculation = CalculateSomethingMore(truckShipping);
var result = DoCalc();

var expected = 18;
Assert.IsTrue(result == expected);
```

NUnit, FluentAssertions, MbUnit, xUnit, etc.. doesn't matter :)

Test:
var truckShipping = Mock.Of<IShipping>   .... ? I want to test the TruckShipping implementation.

and inject that into CalculateSomethingMore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *test TruckShipping implementation* then you need separate tests for `TruckShipping` implementation.

Currently you are testing behavior of `CalculateSomethingMore`, which should return doubled value of cost, calculated by shipping. You don't care which shipping. Responsibility of `CalculateSomethingMore` is asking shipping about it's cost, and doubling that cost:

```
Mock<IShipping> shipping = new Mock<IShipping>();
shipping.Setup(s => s.CalculateCost()).Returns(10);
CalculateSomethingMore sut = new CalculateSomethingMore(shipping.Object);
Assert.That(20, Is.EqualTo(sut.DoCalc()));
shipping.VerifyAll();
```

You can see, that this test uses neither `9` nor `5` as shipping cost. Why? Because you actually don't care what value it will have. Calculating shipping cost is not responsibility of class under test.

Also you need another test for your `TruckShipping` implementation, which will verify, that `TruckShipping` calculates shipping cost correctly (this is a responsibility of your shipping object):

```
TruckShipping sut = new TruckShipping();
Assert.That(9, Is.EqualTo(sut.DoCalc());
```

Comment: Thank you for this clarification that helped my understanding of Mocking and different implementations (which doesn't matter)
I marked this as accepted because of the most comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Janus007 you are welcome :) Btw good practice is to have only one real object in your test (which you are testing). Thus your tests will not fail if implementation of some dependency will change. Also you can simply use `Assert.IsTrue(result)` when you are expecting actual value to be true.

Answer (score 1):

You use mocks to **replace** real dependencies (which often are too complex to instantiate) with **faked**, lightweight objects. Testing mocked object makes no sense at all because essentially, you'll be testing auto-generated code from some 3rd party library.

**Edit**:

It's still unclear why would you want to depend on **concrete implementation**, especially considering you're using IoC and inject `IShipping`. Anyways, I think you want *something that can simulate `TruckShipping`*, but not `TruckShipping` itself. If so, it's simple:

```
var shippingMock = new Mock<IShipping>();
// setting up mock to return 9 makes it behave as if it was TruckShipping
shippingMock.Stub(s => s.CalculateCost()).Returns(9);
var advancedCalculation = CalculateSomethingMore(shippingMock.Object);

var result = DoCalc();

var expected = 18;
Assert.IsTrue(result == expected);
```

Comment: I believe you read my question wrong... It's not the actual mocked object I want to test, but a class that uses the mocked object. Please see my updated question :)

Comment: @Janus007: You rarely use *concrete implementations* in tests, especially with mocking frameworks available. Mocks give you something that can *simulate* those concrete implementations, while being something else. See my edit and let me know if that's what you've been looking for.

Comment: Ahh I think I got it now, I think I was to focused on testing a specific implementation, while in fact that the mock should be setup with the relevant values.
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Moq is not a testing framework, it's a mockinq framework, so it does not provide testing features.

For testing you can use [SharpTestEx](http://sharptestex.codeplex.com), for example you can write:

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyCostIsCorrect()
{
    new TruckShipping()
        .CalculateCost()
        .Should("The TruckShipping implementation returns a wrong cost.").Be.EqualTo(9);
}
```

Comment: That is not a mocked object I'm testing then, why did you omit the mocking?
See my updated question :)

Comment: You want to test TruckShipping implementation, so, why you want to create a mock?
Testing a mocked object doesn't make sense, mockinq is needed to design the problem without worry about the implementation.

Comment: Hi Matteo, my question was not updated... please have a look now.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand what you want to do. You want to test TruckShipping, so, why use a mock?
Or simply you want an example using Moq but not the TruckShipping class?